# Apps need to restarted to refresh profile image

Tags: java, android, mobile

recently i've made a program that can upload image to mysql database via php, and now i'm gonna put that image to my circleImageView, but i've encountered some issue, if i do image update, the image won't refresh until i close the apps and run it again.

here is my code for displaying the image and others from mysql database

```
public void putAllUserData(final String username){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, databaseURL.viewUserData, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    setUsername.setText(username);
                    setFullName.setText(object.getString("nama"));
                    setCountry.setText(object.getString("asal_negara"));
                    setGender.setText(object.getString("jenis_kelamin"));
                    prfImage = object.getString("image_path");

                    if(prfImage.isEmpty()){
                        Toast.makeText(profileActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Picasso.get().load(prfImage).into(profileImage);
                    }
                }
                
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(profileActivity.this, "Error " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(profileActivity.this, "Error " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", username);
            return params;
        }
    };

    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: Are you pulling the data after the user changes his/her profile picture?

Comment: i've tried pulling the data after the user change/update the picture by putting the intent and call it, but still no change at all, it still show the old image before the change/update

Comment: Then how come it works after the app is relaunched? There is something different that you are doing.

Comment: i dont know, if i press back to previous activity and press the profile activity, the intent should be called again right? and it is the same like we call back the data to refresh, but when i do it, it didn't change at all it still use the last image